# Cardinality of set of all bijections $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$; is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I need to find cardinality of a set containing all bijections $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

My proof goes like that:
Let $S$ be the set containing all bijections $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. There exists trivial injection $S \to {\mathbb{N}}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (identity). Therefore $S\subset\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. We define $$F: \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \to S$$ as $$F(f)=\lambda x.\text{if } f(x)=0 \text{ then }2x\text{ else }(2x+1)$$
$F$ is injective. Proof: Assume $F$ isn't injective. Then $\exists f_1, f_2 \in \mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}. f_1 \ne f_2, F(f_1) = F(f_2)\implies\exists x\in\mathbb{N}.f_1(x) \ne f_2(x)\implies F(f_1)(x) \ne F(f_2)(x) \implies F(f_1) \ne F(f_2)$ Contradiction. 
It implies $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\subset S$. $$|\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}| = 2^{\aleph_0} =\mathfrak{c}  \\
|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}| = \mathfrak{c} \\
\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\subset S\subset\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\\
\text{Cantor-Bernstein:} \\
|\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}| \le |S| \le |\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}| \\
|S| = \mathfrak{c}
$$
Is this proof correct?

Comment: Your definition of $F$ isn't clear

Comment: I assume $F(f)(x)=2x+f(x)$?

Comment: Dear god please write your proofs in english. Symbols are not easy to read. A proof should read like a proper collection of grammatically correct sentences.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen: That's much more simple indeed.
Daniel Rust: Sorry for that, I will remember not to do it anymore.
Anyways, is the idea of the proof correct or do I miss something?

Comment: Your $F$ is not well-defined, because for $f = 1_ℕ$, either observe that $F(f)(0) = 1 > 0$ or $F(f)(1) = 3 > 1$ (depending on whether $0 ∈ ℕ$ or not (it’s not)), and since $F(f)(x) ≥ x$, one concludes that $F(f)$ is *not surjective*.

Comment: k.stm: I don't think, that $F(f)$ needs to be surjective. My main goal is to show that $F$ is injective. Then different arguments f would result in different functions returning form $F$. It shows that any function $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ is in $S$ set.  
I assumed that $0\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @EricTroy If $F(f)$ is *not surjective*, it is not an element of $S$, the set of *bijective* functions $ℕ → ℕ$.

Comment: A more pedantic point: presenting an injection from $\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $S$ does not imply $\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}} \subset S$ unless the injection is an inclusion map. It only implies $|\{ 0,1 \}^{\mathbb{N}}| \leq S$.

Comment: I have no idea how to define F function so it would be correct. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eric Troy: I think I got your idea. You break the set of naturals into pairs. Now you flip the pair $n$ or not according to $a_n=1$, or  $a_n=0$. You get for every infinite sequence of $0$ and $1$ $(a_n)$ a bijection of $\mathbb{N}$.

A compact form:

$$(a_n) \mapsto \prod_n (2n-1,2n)^{a_n}$$